# Conditional Independence on multiple variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

Considering five variables, X, Y, Z1, Z2 and Z3. Suppose that: $$ X \not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp Y |Z1,Z2 $$
Also, Y is a function of Z1, Z2 and Z3: $$Y = f(Z1, Z2, Z3)$$
What can be concluded about the relation between X and Z3?

Comment: The answer looks obvious, but what do you think?

Comment: I believe that X depends on Z3 given Z1 and Z2. Can we concluded anything else?

Comment: I can't conclude anything else but the conditional dependence you said.

Comment: Ok great! Can you formaly derived this conclusion?